# Constructor not found by reflection when argument is a subclasses of the constructor's argument declared type

Tags: java, reflection, polymorphism

I'm using reflection to instanciate classes for a specific need.

Current code is like :

```
public final <T> T instanciate(Class<? extends T> a_clazz, Object... args) {

    // Other stuff when no arg...

    Class<?>[] l_argsClasses = getClassesFromObjects(args);
    Constructor<?> constructor = a_clazz.getConstructor(l_argsClasses);
    constructor.newInstance(args)
}
```

Unfortunately, i read that it will not work when given parameters are not exactly the same type in the constructor declaration.

So when i give a subclass, the constructor is not found and I get a NoSuchMethodException.

It seems that there is no mechanism to handle polymorphism here.

**Example :**

```
public class A {

}

public class B extends A {

}

public class Foo extends A {
    public Foo(A a) {

    }
}
```

Will work :

```
instanciate(Foo.class, new A());  // because Foo(A a)
```

Won't work :

```
instanciate(Foo.class, new B());  // because Foo(B b) does't exists
```

Do you have any solution to handle this issue ?

Thank you

Comment: Find all the constructors, loop through `args` to see if they are assignable to the parameters. Be careful, though, because if there are multiple constructors where all the constructors are compatible, you would have to work out which one would be invoked by non-reflective code (or otherwise deal with the ambiguity).

Comment: There's no safe solution, unless one is willing implement some form of signature matching algorithm. Have you considered doing this using a dynamic language, such as Groovy?

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes i was thinking about doing something like that. But i hoped there would be an easier and less bug prone way

Comment: @ernest_k Sadly I have no choice about the langage used here

Answer (score 3):

The `java.beans` package has the classes [`Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/beans/Statement.html) and [`Expression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/beans/Expression.html) which can perform the necessary lookup with sub-type rules:

```
Expression e = new Expression(Foo.class, "new", new Object[]{ new B() });
Foo foo = (Foo)e.getValue();
```

The documentation of the [`execute` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/Statement.html#execute--) describes the special pseudo method name `"new"` for invoking a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I have chosen to use is the methods provided by apache.commons.lang.reflect

It provides two different versions :

- One need to match the parameters types exactly : **invokeExactConstructor()**
- One match the parameter types by assignment compatibility : **invokeConstructor()**

I have tested briefly and it's working. So i'm using it.

Here is the result :

```
public final <T> T instanciate(Class<? extends T> clazz, Object... args) {
    try {
        return clazz.cast(ConstructorUtils.invokeConstructor(clazz, args));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to instanciate Object", e);
    }
}
```

Pretty simpler code which is nice